# XIB Control click programmatically referencing outlets iAD

Tags: ios, xcode, xib, iad, banner

I have an app that I would like to run with iAD. Sadly there is no view controller in interface builder format so I will have to do it programmatically. Can you make referencing outlets through code within the view controller.

Thank you in advanced, everything is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use IB to use iAD.
Declare a UIView in your .h like
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *adView

Synthesize it in .m

Then when you receive an ad, add it to self.adView